# Saber si 2 listas son iguales metodo recursivo

Tags: c++

Estoy intentado implementar una función recursiva que devuelva True si 2 listas son iguales.

lista es un puntero a una estructura de este estilo:

```
struct nodo {
   int elem;
   nodo *sig;
};

typedef nodo *lista;
```

El codigo que hice fue este:

```
bool iguales(lista l1, lista l2) {

   if ((l1 != NULL) && (l2 != NULL) && (l1->elem == l2->elem))
      return (iguales(l1->sig, l2->sig));
   else if ((l1 == NULL) && (l2 == NULL)
      return false;

}
```

Pero está mal ya que al verificar ambas listas y por lo tanto sean NULL pongo que devuelva false.

Es que no se como hacerlo realmente.

Necesito hacerlo recursivamente si o si.

edit: Lo que me cuesta entender es el tema de devolver la funcion, si fuese un procedimiento no tendria problemas para poder hacerlo creo.

Answer (score 1):

He logrado hacer que funcione así:

```
bool iguales(lista l, lista p) {

   if ((l != NULL) && (p != NULL)) {

      if (l->elem != p->elem)
         return false;
      else
         return (iguales(l->sig, p->sig));

   }

   if (l == p) // si son ambas NULL
      return true;
   else
      return false;

}
```

pero no creo que sea con la mejor eficacia posible ¿alguna solución mas eficáz? aunque sea un simple cambio de linea....